# parameter for xcodebuild for using latest sdk.

Tags: xcode, ant, ios, build, hudson

I using ant exec task to execute xcodebuild  to build some iOS projects hudson. I would like to be able to crate script that way that allows not to specify sdk version, because after updating sdk on hudson slave or my iOS projects all my projects failing....

There is is nice option in xcode since sdk 4.2 in target setup `Base SDK - Latest iOS`

and I don't have to provide `-sdk` param in xcodebuild command, but then (i think) it's taken from xcode project and it's bad because then some one can  change target from simulator to device accidentally during commit.

I need something that is constant. I will prefer not to use env variable because I would like to be able to run this ant task also on dev machines and would like not have to renember about setting it on all machines.

Unfortunately `xcodebuild -showsdks` gives only:

```
Mac OS X SDKs:
    Mac OS X 10.4                   -sdk macosx10.4
    Mac OS X 10.5                   -sdk macosx10.5
    Mac OS X 10.6                   -sdk macosx10.6

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 4.2                         -sdk iphoneos4.2

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 3.2             -sdk iphonesimulator3.2
    Simulator - iOS 4.0             -sdk iphonesimulator4.0
    Simulator - iOS 4.1             -sdk iphonesimulator4.1
    Simulator - iOS 4.2             -sdk iphonesimulator4.2
```

I need something like `-sdk iphoneosLatest`. My only idea is to pare output of `xcodebuild -showsdks` with some script, but I don't like this idea.

Comment: Just curious, what do you use Ant for, in conjunction with Hudson and iOS projects? I've just got done setting up Hudson for iOS and didn't have a need for any other tools, wondering if I'm missing out on something.

Answer (score 81):

You can use xcodebuild with the latest SDK using :

- `xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos`, for Device
- `xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator`, for Simulator.

We use these options for our automated builds and it's been working since XCode 3.2.5

Answer (score 10):

I believe you can use `xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos` (no version number) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 8):

I tried @jenningj 's solution and it worked for me. Maciek Sawicki, if this works for you, you should mark it as the right solution.

Also, `xcodebuild -showsdk` should be `xcodebuild -showsdks`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try: `xcodebuild -showsdks | grep -Eo "iphoneos([0-9]{1,}\.)+[0-9]{1,}"`