# xcodebuild doesn't work when specifying -sdk option

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

I'm trying to manually compile an xcode project and I can't manage to compile it using xcodebuild when I specify an SDK through the -sdk option.

This fails:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project "libjpeg.xcodeproj"  -configuration "Release" -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=build build
```

and this works:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project "libjpeg.xcodeproj"  -configuration "Release" -arch i386 CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=build build
```

I have installed XCode 4.3.3 and Command line tools from the Apple's developer page, and everything else it's working without problems. If I build this project using XCode, it works  without problems too. There's no other xcode version in my system.

I should have something really broken in my env, but I can't manage to find it. I'd appreciate any hints you could give me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify something like -sdk iphonesimulator6.0

See this answer: [parameter for xcodebuild for using latest sdk.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314804/parameter-for-xcodebuild-for-using-latest-sdk)